# Serverless offline response issue while sending JSON response in lambda function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless-framework-offline

```
var result = [{
                count : 10,
                data : [{"id":11,"id":22}]
               }];
var response = {
                statusCode: 200,
                count: result.length,
                body: result
            };
            callback(null, response);
```

**Error on Console**

> According to the API Gateway specs, the body content must be
>   stringified. Check your Lambda response and make sure you are invoking
>   JSON.stringify(YOUR_CONTENT) on your body object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error here gives you the solution.
API Gateway's callback expects a string and not a javascript object. You have to stringify it before passing it to the callback:

```
var result = [{
                count : 10,
                data : [{"id":11,"id":22}]
               }];
var response = {
                statusCode: 200,
                count: result.length,
                body: result
            };
            callback(null, JSON.stringify(response));
```

---

EDIT:
Then on the client side parse the JSON string to get it back to an object (this example assume that your client is Javascript too):

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(responseBody);
```

Comment: yes...but i want only ***JSON*** object on client side as response

Comment: Your client should parse the JSON string returned by your service. See my edit.

Comment: Is any alternative way to send JSON object from lambda function...??

Comment: This is a JSON object. You are trying to send a JavaScript object. My code transforms it in JSON for transport and then back to a JavaScript object at destination. You can’t send a JavaScript object directly.

Comment: Same code of mine is working on server and also get proper response.....but it fails while I m cloning from git lab and run it on locally.....its shows  **According to the API Gateway specs, the body content must be stringified. Check your Lambda response and make sure you are invoking JSON.stringify(YOUR_CONTENT) on your body object**

Comment: My solutions does exactly what the specs tells you to do. It’s possible the API Gateway now does JSON.stringify for you if you pass a JavaScript object. Serverless does not locally, so just listen to the warning and stringify your output.

Comment: hi Quentin Hayout....fixed above issue using **serverless-offline": "3.25.6"** version